# AngularJS issue (POST 405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I am new to Angular. I am learning about the $http service and currently trying to send JSON data via POST. Unfortunately, I am getting an error. I tried reading other people's posts concerning this problem, but I can't seem to understand what the issue is.

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this error and suggest ways of fixing it ?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller = "ctrl">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model = "newDJ_name">
        <button ng-click = "addDJ(newDJ_name)">Add new DJ name</button>
        <button ng-click = "show()">Show DJs</button>
    </form>

    <div ng-repeat = "dj in djs">

        {{dj.name}}

    </div>
</body>

<script src = "angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "httpService.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module ("app",[]);

app.controller ("ctrl",function ($scope,$http) {
$scope.show = function () {
        $http.get('djs.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.djs = data;
        })
    };
$scope.addDJ = function (newName) {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/Documents/Angular/djs.json',{name : newName})
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.djs = data;
        })
        .error (function(data) {
            console.log(":(");
        })
    }


});
```

**JSON file**

```
[{
    "name": "Adam Beyer",
    "city": "Sweden",
    "genre": "techno",
    "label": "Drumcode"
}, {
    "name": "Richie Hawtin",
    "city": "Detroit",
    "genre": "techno",
    "label": "Minus"
}, {
    "name": "Solomun",
    "city": "Undefined",
    "genre": "techno",
    "label": "Dyinamic"
}]
```

[When I try to add a new dj name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvTpm.png)

Comment: Your API do not except POST as method, it's backend API issue. Have you tried with Postman kind of API testing tool?

Comment: Seems you are trying to post data to you a `.json` file instead of a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make POST your data directly to a .json file. This is not possible.

Instead, write a webservice endpoint on your server that:
-Accepts the 'POST' phrase and payload data
-Writes the data to a file, in your case, a .JSON file
-Returns a meaningful response back to your Angular app, based on the success or failure of creating the file.

Note - if you are trying to update a .JSON file that already contains data, you will probably need to parse the existing file as JSON, mutate it with the new data, then save it back to the file.

If you were to change the webservice phrase to GET, you should typically see a successful response:

```
// This will work
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/Documents/Angular/djs.json')
```

Comment: Glad to help, please do not hesitate mark this answer as correct if it helped you